# Latex - article frontmatter

Tags: article, front-matter

I am writing a report using class `article`. Since I have already started with article, I want to know if there is any wait to have `frontmater` and `mainmatter` like in class book. I want my introduction section number to be 1 and all titles (and page numbers) before to be with roman numerals.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you really sure you have to stick with article class? There are other good classes out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in your file..

```
\makeatletter

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  %\@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}

\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
 % \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}

\newcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
 % \@mainmatterfalse
   }

\makeatother
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's certainly possible; you just have to define `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`.  Here's an example where I've defined `\backmatter`, as well, just as a demonstration.

As I understand you, you want two things:  (1) Frontmatter sections to be numbered with Roman numerals, and page numbers to be romanettes; (2) Mainmatter sections to be numbered with Arabic numerals, and page numbers to be Arabic.  I'm assuming that you want page numbers to start over again when you hit `\mainmatter`, which is the typical practice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\frontmatter{%
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
}%

\def\mainmatter{%
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
}%

\def\backmatter{%
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
}%

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\section{Why Do This?}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Because I Can!}

\lipsum[2]

\mainmatter

\section{See?  It works!}

\lipsum[3]

\section{It's the best this way!}

\lipsum[4]

\backmatter

\section{And We Even Get Appendices!}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

This will give you the following:

[image]

Of course, you may want the division between front and back matter to be marked in some other way; add that to the code above if you do.

Answer (score 3):

So you are searching for an article that look like a book.Hmm ... Why not a book that look like an article?

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents 
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
Some text
\end{document}
```